# Retrieving data from a database in ASP.NET Razor Pages

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, razor

I found online how to submit an image uploaded from the user into my database. Here is the code that I use:

**Create.cshtml**

```
@page
@model SummerFling.Pages.Products.CreateModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Create</title>
</head>
<body>

<h4>Product</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Product.ProductName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Product.ProductName" class="form-control" required />
                <span asp-validation-for="Product.ProductName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Product.ProductShortDesc" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Product.ProductShortDesc" class="form-control" required />
                <span asp-validation-for="Product.ProductShortDesc" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Product.ProductLongDesc" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Product.ProductLongDesc" class="form-control" required />
                <span asp-validation-for="Product.ProductLongDesc" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Product.ProductPrice" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Product.ProductPrice" class="form-control" required />
                <span asp-validation-for="Product.ProductPrice" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <dl>
                <dt>
                    <label asp-for="FileUpload.FormFile"></label>
                </dt>
                <dd>
                    <input asp-for="FileUpload.FormFile" type="file" required>
                </dd>
            </dl>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
</body>
</html>
```

And in the Create.cshtml.cs class file, I have the code that gets the data from the form and submits it to my database:

**Create.cshtml.cs**

```
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
// more details see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await FileUpload.FormFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

        // Upload the file if less than 2 MB
        if (memoryStream.Length < 2097152)
        {
            var imageRecord = new Image()
            {
                ProductImage1 = memoryStream.ToArray()
            };

            _context.Image.Add(imageRecord); // Add the created image record to the Image database.

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            _context.Product.Add(Product); // Add the created product record to the Product database

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("File", "The file is too large.");
            return Page();
        }
    }

}
```

Now, on the /Index page I want to fetch all of the data stored in my database and show this on the page. I have no problem doing this for the data that is stored in the Product table, but I'm struggling to understand the logic of how I should do this for the images stored inside the Image table.

**Index.cshtml**

```
@page
@model SummerFling.Pages.Products.IndexModel
@using WebMatrix.Data;

@{
    Layout = null;
    var queryString = "SELECT ProductImage1 FROM Image WHERE ProductID LIKE @0";
    var db = Database.Open("SummerFlingProductContext");

    // appsettings.json
    //   "ConnectionStrings": {
    //       "SummerFlingProductContext": "Server=127.0.0.1,1433;Database=SummerFling;User Id=SA;Password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    //    }

}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <a asp-page="Create">Create New</a>
    </p>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Product[0].ProductName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Product[0].ProductShortDesc)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Product[0].ProductLongDesc)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Product[0].ProductPrice)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Product)
            {

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductShortDesc)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductLongDesc)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductPrice)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @db.QuerySingle(queryString, item.ProductID);
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ProductID">Edit</a> |
                        <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.ProductID">Details</a> |
                        <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ProductID">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Index.cshtml.cs**

```
namespace SummerFling.Pages.Products
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SummerFling.Data.SummerFlingProductContext _context;

        public IndexModel(SummerFling.Data.SummerFlingProductContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IList<Product> Product { get; set; }
        public IList<Image> Image { get; set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            Product = await _context.Product.ToListAsync();
            IList<Image> Image = await _context.Image.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Im struggling to work out where and how I should code the logic to get the images from the Image table and show the image alongside all the other data for each row. (Right now, entry 1 in the Image table contains images that relate to entry 1 in the Product table).

Do I code this inside the .cshtml.cs file in a similar way to how the data from the Product table is retrieved? And how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the image in the Controller that displays your `Index.cshtml` View.
Also there add the image to your (list of) `IndexModel` and display it the same way you display `ProductName` and `ProductShortDes`.

In general you'd want to have as little logic in the View as possible and especially the database ac.

Comment: What type should the list of images be? Do I convert the byte stream into an object before storing in the list?

Comment: i.e. what type should the image be so that I can display it in the view?

Comment: @Hdot You can display images like this  
`<img alt="" src="data:image/png;base64<Some Base64 data here>" />`
You can store the base64 in your viewModel like this
`viewmodel.base64Image = Convert.ToBase64String(theByteArray, 0, theByteArray.Length);`
and display it like this
`<img alt="" src="data:image/png;base64@model.base64Image " />`